# android osmdroid offline map how to use object search

Tags: android, search, maps, offline, osmdroid

I use offline osmdroid maps in my application and I want to add search objects on the map to application. I can't find any information, it's possible or not. Anyone have any expirience with searching in osmdroid offline maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded, that it's impossible. I generated my own objects database and get information from there.